# Getting system.out into an automatic generated JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextarea, system.out

I used the Netbeans form to auto generate a `JTextArea` which I am planning to use to display the system.out, but I have only gotten these lines:

```
jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
jTextArea1.setRows(5);
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
```

Can anyone please show me how to use turn this into a working text area for displaying the `System.out`?

Comment: Just use `setText()` on the TextArea instead of using System.out.

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was to change the system.out to an append with a stringbuilder in my main class.

```
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Michel's Muziek Magazijn.accdb");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mmm WHERE "+combo+" = '"+text+"'");
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (rs.next()) {
            strBuilder.append( rs.getString(2) + "\t \t" + rs.getString(3)+ "\t \t" + rs.getString(4));
            strBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    jTextArea1.setText(strBuilder.toString());
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) which allows you to redirect output to a text component.